# How can I achieve an infinite scrolling animation effect in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, animation, xamarin, parallax

I'm making an app in Xamarin Android and I want to achieve something like this:
https://github.com/Q42/AndroidScrollingImageView

Basically, it's an infinite scrolling image animation. I'm really new to android development let alone Xamarin so I'm at a loss here. I dont think the Translate animation in XML would work here. I'm thinking of translating 2 ImageViews but I dont know how to do that outside XML.

Is there a library similar to that one for Xamarin? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cool thing about Xamarin.Android is that you can easily reuse existing Java libraries. If you are fine with using the [AndroidScrollingImageView](https://github.com/Q42/AndroidScrollingImageView) library instead of rolling out your own implemenetation, here's what you should do:

1. Clone or download the project to your own computer and build the library.
2. As a result, you'll get a JAR file that contains the `AndroidScrollingImageView` control.
3. Create a new [binding project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/) and import the JAR file.
4. Xamarin.Android wraps the library with C# wrappers so you can invoke Java code from C#.
5. Now you can use the control in your AXML layouts and call the methods in code.

It's worth reading the binding article to understand how this works. There's also a good binding library example [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CircleImageView-Xamarin.Android), where James Montemagno does exactly what you want to do. You might want to study it to see how the binding works in real life.

Comment: Would try this immediately! Thanks for this!

Comment: Also sorry, how do I go about building the project?